# inode reference counter how does it work?

Tags: linux, kernel, inode, vfs

I understood that If one file is used by one process, the inode->i_count.counter is incremented.

I made a simple C program to open a file wihout closing it (infinite waiting loop), and this i_count is not incremented, is it normal ?

```
int main(){
    FILE *file1 = NULL;
    file1 = fopen("file1", "r");
    
    while(1)
            sleep(1);  

    if (file1)
            fclose(file1); 

    return 0;
}
```